# Grails - Issue using hibernate domain class

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, one-to-many, has-many

I am trying to reuse my hibernate domain class in my grails project, it contains two domain classes `User` and `UserHistory`, where `User` class is like

`class User {
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<UserHistory> userHistories = new LinkedHashSet<UserHistory>();
   //some fields and getter, setter
}`

`class UserHistory {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
    private User user;
    //some fields and getter, setter
}`

And in my `UserController` I having a method like

```
    User user = User.findByUserName("suganthan")
    user.someField = "somevalue"
    UserHistory history = new UserHistory(someField:"somevalue")
    //Set<UserHistory> historySet = new HashSet<UserHistory>();
    //historySet.add(history)
    user.addToHistories( history ) // Error
    user.save(failOnError: true)
```

But the line `user.addToHistories( history )` is throwing the error `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`. Can someone help me on this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure since your User class isn't annotated with the Grails/GORM static property of static hasMany = [histories: UserHistory] the dyanmic addTo* method isn't going to be available to you. Those dynamic methods are only available to Grails Domain classes. I think you will have to use whatever a typical Hibernate/POJO implementation would be.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore, yes I don't have `static hasMany = [histories: UserHistory]`in user class

Comment: Then since this isn't a Grails domain class as such you won't be able to take advantage of the GORM dynamic methods.

Comment: @Joshua Moore thank u, I got it, anyway I need do some research on this. Thank you for you and your time. Really helpful

Comment: @ Joshua Moore But this one working `User.findByUserName(username)`. addTo* not working might be 'cause there is not `hasMany`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60292/discussion-between-joshua-moore-and-suganthan).